# How to clone a project and stay up to date with it?

Tags: git, fork, clone

I'd like to clone an existing project ([Octopress](http://octopress.org/)) to make my own blog.
This project is hosted on GitHub, but I would like to use Bitbucket for my repository.

What would be the best workflow to clone the repo, use it to make my own blog and stay up to date with the changes of the original repository?

I was thinking about cloning the repo, adding a remote (bitbucket), push to the remote when I make changes, and pull updates from the origin when I need them.

Would this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't really a good way of staying up to date. As with any Git project, you simply need to `git fetch` and `get merge`, and resolve any conflicts that come up.

Unfortunately, the Octopress people are abusing Git as a distribution system, so they've really screwed you here. You're *going* to get conflicts, since you must modify their code to use it. They should be shipping their product as a Gem so that you can use it without modifying their code.